# Roboto Font changes its look

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, embedded-fonts

My client e-mailed me a Word document and the font files to display it (Roboto, from Google I believe).  I installed them before opening the document.

The document's Title style is in Roboto Condensed Bold 36. But when I "reset" the font (highlighting and pressing Ctrl-space), it changes slightly. (It becomes narrower and lighter).

I examined both before and after with the various Font dialogs, and they insist that both versions are Roboto Condensed Bold 36.

Going forward, I'm supposed to use the "after" version. But when I save the doc as a PDF, it displays as the "before" version.  I had even set the Word option to embed the font.

I really need the font to be the "after" version; better yet, to know how to control this transformation.

EDIT: Using Word 365. (Which i believe is currently Word 2016)

Comment: It could be relevant; WHICH version of Microsoft Word is in play here? Find out, please, with File | Account | About Word - and once you know, please click on `edit` at left above, and add that into your original question.